# LWC Lightning-input custom validation for max length, no error message comes on blur

Tags: lightning-web-components, error-messages

```
<pre>
        <lightning-input type="text" label="Enter some text" max-length=10
                 message-when-too-long="Max 10 characters allowed"></lightning-input>

</pre>
```

I can't see this error, because input field is not allowing me to enter more than 10 characters.

Comment: <div class="slds-p-around_medium lgc-bg">
            <lightning-input type="text" label="Enter some text" max-length=10
                     message-when-too-long="Max 10 characters allowed"></lightning-input>
        </div>

Answer (score 0):

This error is essentially impossible to trigger under normal circumstances, which is good. It's better to restrict bad input than it is to just report it.

That said, if you want to actually see it, set the value to something too big:

```
    <lightning-input type="text" label="Enter some text" max-length=10
             message-when-too-long="Max 10 characters allowed" value="1234567890123456"></lightning-input>
```

And then edit the text such that it is still invalid.